# Storing items in washroom (protection from moisture)

Tags: bathroom, furniture, moisture, storage

I've moved into a flat which has a washroom (shower, washing machine and sink) which is relatively huge in comparison to the rest of the flat; How might I be able to store items in this room without them being damaged due to the humidity caused by usage of the shower and washing machine/drying racks?

There is a small fan in the wall which is somewhat effective at cycling air through the room (it turns on automatically once the humidity passes a given threshold) but it is still noticeably "steamy" in the room for a while after showering.

If I simply put some large cabinets in the room, I fear that e.g. textile and paper items in the room will slowly be ruined by the moisture; Are there no furniture(-like) solutions which can allow me to easily store these items in the room while keeping them dry?

Answer (score 2):

You can run a test with some scrap paper or something, but I suspect this won't be a problem. Towels, toilet paper, and tissues are all commonly stored in bathrooms with no ill effects, and many vanity cabinets are made of particleboard - notoriously susceptible to moisture.

Just make sure to run the fan every time the bath or shower is used (don't wait for it to turn on automatically) and for 20-30 minutes after.